# Docker for sandboxing desktop (GUI) applications & games

Tags: windows, docker, sandbox, sandboxie

My idea is to install Docker on my Windows 10 computer, and run some programs in their own container. This would have various pros:

- Having some applications separated from others.
- Being able to run two instances of programs such as Skype where I am logged in with two different user account.
- Programs not contaminating the registry of the main system.
- Being able to easily transfer the application and all of it's files, folders, registry keys to another computer.

What I am unsure about is whether Docker on Windows works the same way as on Linux, and that is only using one kernel? I have a feeling that on Windows it offers an (almost) fully virtualized environment to the programs, and a partial virtualization is not possible on Windows.

My questions would be the following:

- Would installing programs in Docker on Windows take up (considerably) more space than installing it normally?
- Would Windows form applications work in Docker?
- Would hardware accelarated programs, such as games run in Docker, and if yes, would there be a noticable difference in performance?

I have previously used Sandboxie, which had it's faults, and I know Docker wasn't technically created for this purpose, but could it be used as a free replacement for Sandboxie?

Comment: Windows 10 insider preview has Windows Sandbox feature.

Comment: Hmm... When will that feature come out? I doubt I can use it anyways, as our systems are running Windows 10 LTSB/LTSC.

Comment: Windows Sandbox is extremely low performance. It works well for very simple CPU bound tasks. GPUs are not properly supported.
So it's not a solution to the question